# Audio missing from clips, standard solution not working

Tags: audio

Adobe Premier, Windows 10: I accidentally deleted some audio from some clips I had edited in the timeline by just moving one clip's audio over the other clip's audio in the same audio lane. I have looked for solutions, and the popular answer seems to be to use match frame and then hit "." This will reproduce the same clip with no audio on my timeline. Frustrating! I can find the original clip in the project, and it still has audio, and I could redo all the editing I have done so far, but that would take hours. Is there an actual solution to this issue? Am I pressing "F ." incorrectly? I've also tried "Generate audio waveform" - no luck. I refuse to believe that accidentally dragging one track's audio over another track's is such an irreversible mistake in such a high end program.
Please help